# Display recent item in MongoDB collection in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection that collects sensor data from an Arduino published via MQTT. I would like to create an AngularJS client page that displays the most recent sensor data. Is this doable?

Comment: This sounds doable, just make sure you are including time stamps in you mongoDB collection so you'll be able to pull the most recent data

Comment: Yeah i got time stamps on my data collected in MongoDB. Do you any link that could guide me in this pursuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB you can get the latest data with a query like this:

```
db.yourCollection.find().sort({ datetime: -1 }).limit(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to display my collection in intervals of 15mins, 30mins, 1hr etc. This is what my data looks like `{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db4da4a13fbf6d620f341"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:35:54.844Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }`. What do you think.

Comment: But if you have another question ask it in another question, with adding some sample data and your expected results ;).

Comment: Okay! Can I translate the edited solution to AngularJS? The previous solution was exactly what i needed. I was able to get it. Thanks.